# Does knowledge affects probability?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 5 coins: 2 are double-headed, 1 is double-tailed and 2 are normal.
(a) You close your eyes, pick a coin at random and toss it. What is the probability
that the lower face is heads?
(b) You open your eyes and see that the coin is showing heads. What is the probability
that the lower face is heads?

Answer for `part a` is 3/5.
For the part b the answers is 2/3, because only Double headed coins can show double head and therefor (2/5)/(3/5) = 2/3. 
However, I am slightly concerned because we already know, that choosen coin is not Double tailed coin. Thus answer should be 5/6 = (1/2)/(3/5), as our sample space is {HH,HH,HT,HT}, is not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the heads on the double-headed coin (even if we can't distinguish them visibly). Hence, there are in fact $6$ possible outcomes in the sample space where heads is face-up (two for each double-headed coin, one for each single-headed coin, none for the double-tailed coin), and of those, $4$ have heads face-down as well.

Comment: I mean, have we reduce number of coins from 5 to 4, because we know that double tail coin is not there or we should always consider original sample space?

Comment: We have indeed reduced the number of coins from $5$ to $4$, but we have reduced our (effective) sample space from $10$ to $6$, since we know that neither of the $2$ possible double-tailed coin-flip outcomes occurred, nor did the tails-up outcome occur for either of the $2$ single-headed coins.

Comment: To put it another way, if you see a head, you are twice as likely to be looking at a double-headed coin, which "doubles" the share of outcomes those coins have compared to the "normal" coins.